# welcome. denied!!! press enter to quit

Tags: python, passwords

I tried to create a username and password program for my family, but when I open it it says:

```
Welcome.
Denied!!!
Press enter to quit.
```

Can anyone solve my problem? The code is below:

```
print ("Welcome.")

username = ("Please enter your username.")

if username == ("mom, savanna, joseph"):

    print ("Granted.")

    password = input ("Please enter your password.")

    if password == ("1975, 2000, jesus"):

        print ("Granted.")

        question = ("Do you like it?")

        if question == ("yes"):

            print ("I thought you would.")

        if question == ("no"):

            print ("I guess I could do better")

        else:

            print ("error")

    else:

        print ("Denied!!!")

else:

    print ("Denied!!!")

input ("press enter to quit")
```

Comment: Please check your code more carefully. There are numerous small mistakes. Are you new to coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue is on this line:

```
username = ("Please enter your username.")
```

I presume you mean to have an `input` function call there.

```
username = input("Please enter your username.")
```

That will solve your immediate rejection issue.

You also have the same issue on this line:

```
question = ("Do you like it?")
```

Which should also be:

```
question = input("Do you like it?")
```

Comment: the current code would still fail on the next `if`.

Comment: @Joel Not if his password is `mom, savanna, joseph`. Unless you mean the other missing `input`, which I just added.

Comment: It would actually need to be username, not password "mom, savanna, joseph"`  (note I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing:

You are new to code. We can see that here. However, there is always room for improvement and you can learn from mistakes. Some people make odd code sometimes ;)

I have created a working model for you to see where you went wrong.

```
print ("Welcome.")
username = input("Please enter your username.")
if username in ("mom", "savanna", "joseph"):
    password = input("Please enter your password.")
    if password in ("1975","2000","jesus"):
        print ("Granted.")
        question = input("Do you like it?")
        if question == ("yes"):
            print ("I thought you would.")
        elif question == ("no"):
            print ("I guess I could do better")
        else:
            print ("error")

else:
    print ("Denied!!!")
    break
```

You typed `question = ("Do you like it?")` without the `input`. This is important since it actually lets the user type something.

You wrote `if username == ("mom,savanna,joseph")`
this means that if the username is `mom,savanna,joseph` then you get in. obviously you wanted only one of these to get in. the Boolean operator `or` can help a lot in this situation.

Notice how I used `elif` instead of `if`. Python can only have one if and one else. but as many elifs as you want. It means else-if.

**EDIT:**

After reading Joel's comment, I noticed that you probably want Mom's password to be 1975, Savannah's to be 2000, and Joseph's to be jesus. How do you think you can do that by using my code given here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to have 3 different usernames, and mom's password to be 1975 etc.

```
password = {"mom":"1975", "savanna":"2000", "joseph":"jesus"}

print ("Welcome.")
username = input("Please enter your username.")
if username in password:  #if x in dict returns True if dict has the key x
    print ("Granted.")
    mypassword = input ("Please enter your password.")
    if mypassword == password[username]:
        print ("Granted.")
        answer = input("Do you like it?")
        if answer == ("yes"):
            print ("I thought you would.")
        elif answer == ("no"):
            print ("I guess I could do better")
        else:
            print ("error")
    else:
        print ("Denied!!!")

else:

    print ("Denied!!!")

input("press enter to quit")
```

You may want to put a loop around it so that it doesn't have to get restarted if there's a bad entry.

Comment: He-hey, thats smart. +1 from me :)

Comment: You have the same information twice; make it `if username in password:`. Also, have a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

you are asking `if username == ("mom, savanna, joseph")` instead of `if username in ("mom, savanna, joseph")`

if you entered in "mom" for username when it asked you, it would be like comparing this

```
if "mom" == ("mom, savanna, joseph"):
```

`("mom, savanna, joseph")` and `"mom"` are not equal

to check if an item is in a list use the `in` keyword

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 3 in x
True
```

you also did the same thing when checking `if password ==`

also @Alexander O'Mara is correct, you never did the `input()` for username

Comment: ("mom", "savanna", "joseph") no?

Comment: You meant `if "mom" in` not `if "mom" ==`